# Is there a way to create a UIImage without orientation?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiimageview, crop

I am about to crop images but facing the orientation issue while creating image using `CGImageCreateWithImageInRect`.

`CGImageCreateWithImageInRect` crops the image based on UIImage orientation so I cannot get the right images as I want.

I want the plain image from the UIImage/maybe-camera-image without orientation meta data.

Is there a way to achieve this?

**EDIT:**
I have the some selected rect of the 'UIImage'. If I apply the crop on the 'UIImage' it gives different output with some other orientation

Comment: I found the way myself. Just took a screen shot of the image before cropping, then i cropped!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(src.CGImage, croppingRect);
    UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:1.0f orientation:src.imageOrientation];
```

Comment: we need to set the 'orientation:' for 'src.CGImage' on cropping or before,not after the cropping done.

Answer (score 0):

Could help someone!

```
-(UIImage*) removeImageOrientation:(UIImage*)ImgtakenByUser
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(ImgtakenByUser.size);
    [ImgtakenByUser drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, ImgtakenByUser.size.width, ImgtakenByUser.size.height)];
    UIImage *_image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return _image;

}
```

Thanks!